# What are some examples of classes that should be both noncopyable and nonmovable?

Tags: c++, c++11

Most noncopyable objects are noncopyable because it's nonsensical or problematic to have more than one (e.g., `std::unique_ptr`), but moving them is still fine. But what are some examples where there is good reason to make an object neither copyable nor movable?

Comment: Remember that moving an object breaks all pointers and references to it...

Answer (score 5):

When it implements the singleton pattern. If there's only ever going to be one and only one instance of a class, then there really is no point to moving or copying it.

Comment: That said, nothing should implement the singleton 'pattern' in the first place.

Comment: @Xeo I would largely agree but there are cases where it does make sense. I can count on one hand the number of times it has made sense in the past 10 years but when it has...

Answer (score 1):

std::condition_variable (see here: [condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)).

I suspect due to potential data races when trying to move.

Comment: And `std::mutex` for even more complex reasons.

Comment: @peppe I guess we would need a mutex when trying to move the mutex ;)